# how can I add this formatted text for a help page in my ios app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have this help page I want to add to my application, but I'm not sure of how to format it. At the moment it's just an image in a scrollview, but surely there's a better way?

[image: help page]

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully people find it useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many apps use a WebView to display formatted text. You can then use CSS to style your content as needed.

Comment: This really is the best way. Neither `UILabel` not `UITextView` allows for varying formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You could use NSAttribuatedString + RTLabel to display it (or of cause the default cheat of a UIWebView).

To display RichText (NSAttribuatedString use one of these).

- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rtlabel
- https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML
- http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/
- https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel
- https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

Use webview to and with webservices so u can change it later so on

Comment: He doesn't need webservices. He can just revise the html file in any updates to the app.

Comment: indeed but if u need to change it later on those page u can just use that link with some update which will affect also in app.without resubmission.

Comment: This approach is good, but be sure to cache it if your app is meant to be used offline as well.